# Fibonacci Series Extension

Tags: c#, sequence, fibonacci

How can I write a code in C# to find the sum of letters

If A=0;B=1,C=A+B,D=B+C,E=C+D.....

Example CD=1+2=3,

I have tried this way where input is string and output is sum of letter

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static (int output1)
    public static void Main(string input1)
    {
        // your code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: We are not here to do your "Home Work"

Comment: @ÁngelDiMaría Add this for answer :D You make my day :)

Comment: the best way to find the answer is `Pay Attention in Class`

Comment: I have tried to write code for this question. Please help with the code.

Comment: I have to solve this problem without using dictionary list

Comment: @pravprab An object reference is required to access non-static member- Compilation error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer without using dictionary list

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string test = "abcdef";
            int sum = 0;  
            foreach (char c in test)
            {
                int letterNumber = char.ToUpper(c) - 64;  
                sum += rtnDegint(letterNumber);
            }  
            Console.WriteLine(sum);
        }

        int rtnDegint(int n)
        {
            int first = 0, second = 1, next = 0, c;  
            for (c = 0; c < n; c++)
            {
                if (c <= 1)
                    next = c;
                else
                {
                    next = first + second;
                    first = second;
                    second = next;
                }
            }
            return next;
        }
    }
```

Comment: got it static int rtnDegint(int n)